# Use of undeclared type 'UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey'

Tags: ios, swift2

Recently converted a project to Swift 2.2 and running into issues that didn't exist prior.  I've tried searching for a workaround but haven't found any similar posts.

Use of undeclared type 'UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey'.

I can't tell what's wrong with this code in the AppDelegate.swift:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    //UIToolbar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    return true
}
```

Comment: Did you mean Swift 3 or Swift 2?

Comment: I must be behind the times... I recently updated to 2.2...

Apple Swift version 2.2 (swiftlang-703.0.18.8 clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the method signature to

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

The signature is modified to `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool`  in swift 3

Comment: Thank you Mathews, that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3 the method is changed to:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
return true
```

}